# Can't get single column value from database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to get a single value from 1 record in the DB but have an error...

```
$gamer_name = Gamer::where('user_id', $gamer_id)->first()->name;
```

As a result, I have this...

> Trying to get property of non-object

If I remove `->name` from the request like this

`$gamer_name = Gamer::where('user_id', $gamer_id)->first();`

then I get `App\Gamer Object` data instead of a name. I can't just get the single value from a single row with Eloquent.

Comment: Have you tried to do it like this :
$gamer_name = Gamer::where('user_id', $gamer_id)->first()[0]->name;

Comment: Try this `Gamer::where('user_id', $gamer_id)->first(['name'])`

Comment: In theory, your code should work perfectly fine. Something else doesn't seem right here... are you sure that is all of your code for getting these values? Please post a dump of  `$gamer_name = Gamer::where('user_id', $gamer_id)->first();` because it should return a collection - though it doesn't seem to be the case?

Comment: There is a possibility that the query result is empty, thus giving you a null when you call `first()`.

Comment: @Wreigh I was thinking this, hence why I requested OP to post a dump - but they also said `then I get all App\Gamer Object data instead of a name` so the presumption is that the query response is not empty

Comment: `first()` will return `Gamer` model, so you can access property `name`. But `first()` also return NULL when no record exists.

Comment: @mr.boris, did you add `name` in `fillable` array in `Gamer` class?

Comment: @NgocNam I think that is self evident based on previous comments and the fact OP is using it to get the model in the first place

Comment: @NgocNam The `$fillable` shouldn't matter here as OP is only retrieving values and not attempting to mass assign them in this instance.

Comment: @AshleyBrown You are right!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pluck()` for that purpose

```
$gamer_name = Gamer::where('user_id', $gamer_id)->pluck('name');
```

Documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects

Answer (score 0):

Using a query builder instead of a collection, but it should work:

```
$gamer_name = DB::table("gamers")->where("user_id", $gamer_id)->value("name");
```

[From the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries):

> If you don't even need an entire row, you may extract a single value from a record using the value method. This method will return the value of the column directly:
>
> `$email = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->value('email');`

Answer (score 0):

there are various solution for this query and on of the easiest may be

```
$gamer_name = Gamer::where('user_id', $gamer_id)->first()->select('name');
```

next one

```
$gamer_name = Gamer::where('user_id', $gamer_id)->first()->value('name');
```